# WebClient having problems

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make an Image Archive(r) for RADAR Images etc. WebClient Seems to be having issues with me. Or I don't know what I'm doing.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
{
     wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
     wc.DownloadFile("http://www.weather.gov/images/dlh/WxStory/FileL.png?", browserFileDialog.SelectedPath() + ".png");
}
```

I have a Browse File Dialog in place, Whenever I download the File. It would save to the Desktop, And get the name of the folder selected in "Browse File Dialog". Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I forgot to say, I want the user to be able to select the location to save it to.

Comment: What's the actual problem you're having?

Comment: I want to be able to save the file to the actual location, and not have it save to the desktop.

Comment: Like I have said, It ends up saving to the Desktop and not the location selected.

Comment: @JayBay Is `SelectedPath` a method? I thought it was a string, but you're using it like a method.

Comment: Can you include the code where you're opening the `FolderBrowserDialog`?

Comment: @JayBay Also, you're not specifying a name for the file. You're getting a directory and adding an extension.

Comment: Dialog_WeatherStory.ShowDialog();

Comment: I'm calling it on a Button Click statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [SaveFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the path you want:

```
using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog())
{
    // This only allows you to choose PNG, you may want to change it.
    sfd.Filter = "Image Files (*.png)|*.png";

    DialogResult result = sfd.ShowDialog();

    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
            wc.DownloadFile("http://www.weather.gov/images/dlh/WxStory/FileL.png?", sfd.FileName);
         }
     }
 }
```

There are some more parameters for SaveFileDialog that might be of use which I have missed out for brevity. I've also put no error handling in here so you need to do that too.

Comment: I want to be able to save the file without the user seeing any Dialog what-so-ever.

Comment: You say in your question that you want the user to pick the location, but here you say you don't want them to see a dialog. You can do one or the other, but not both. Which is it?

Comment: I wasn't reading that right :o. Thank you for the help. It's fine.